# Registering an ActiveX-Exe with WIX 3.6

Tags: wix, wix3.6

For the ActiveX-DLLs the tool Heat.exe works great, but for executable ActiveX-components (the one who wanted to be self-registered with "foo.exe /RegServer") it handles the exe-file like an ordinary file with no entries for registering (clsid, ...).
Is there a  way to handle this without using a custom action?

Comment: If you have the source, you should be able to determine what ProgIds and CLSIDs that it registers, and create the WiX with <Class/> and <RegistryValue/> manually. If you don't have the source, I'd use the Process Monitor tool from Microsoft to see what registry entries foo.exe /RegServer creates.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If this is the only way, I'll keep my solution with the custom action. In my opinion it's not very compfortable to juggle with these GUIDs. To many things to forget:)